# TypeORM does not connect successfully to my Postgres

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am using Express, Postgres and TypeORM for a small website.

I am having problem in connecting TypeORM with my Postgres.

**index.ts**

```
( async ()=>{
    console.log("before")  <-- This gets printed
    await createConnection()
    console.log("after") <-- This does NOT get printed
    app.listen(4000, ()=>{
        console.log('express server is listening on port 4000')
    })

})()
```

**ormconfig.json**

```
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "postgres",
   "password": "postgres",
   "database": "jwtauthexample",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": true,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

**I created a postgres database and user as follow**

1. `brew install postgres`
2. `psql postgres` on my terminal
3. `CREATE DATABASE jwtauthexample`
4. `CREATE USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD postgres`
5. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE jwtauthexample TO postgres`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The same `index.ts` code was working some weeks ago. Then I deleted postgres and it is not able to connect anymore using the same procedure I use all the time.

I am pretty sure the problem is with `await createConnection()` because it does not execute the line `console.log("before)` once I run:
`yarn start` (with nodemon)

Comment: I know you solved your own question but if you add a try catch around the await you will get a rejected promise that will tell you why it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I forgot to run:
`npm install pg --save` inside my app

If you use yarn do:
`yarn add pg`

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this problem earlier, It appears to be a problem with pg, after upgrading pg version it worked fine, please do the following

**1. npm uninstall pg --save**

**2. npm install pg --save**

I was running version 6.4.2 and now it will install the latest version (which for me was 8.7.1 )

Comment: You'd expect an error or exception but this was indeed the case.